# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "<name>" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have looked through similar answers, but it didn't work for my question.

I use Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04 and try to change the database of a Rails project from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL. After I modified the Gemfile, executed the bundle and completed the modification of database.yml, I proceeded to $rails db:create.

Finally, I tried to do $rails db:migrate, and the following error occurred:

```
== 20211211075029 CreateSpaceUsers: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:space_users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "Spaces" does not exist
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:110:in `exec'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:110:in `async_exec'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:46:in `block in execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:696:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:695:in `block in log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:687:in `log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:45:in `execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:322:in `create_table'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:929:in `block in method_missing'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `say_with_time'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `method_missing'
/mnt/c/projects/Ksnew/db/migrate/20211211075029_create_space_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:867:in `exec_migration'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:851:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1329:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1328:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `each'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `block in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1401:in `block in with_advisory_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `block in with_advisory_lock_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `with_advisory_lock_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1397:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "Spaces" does not exist
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:110:in `exec'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:110:in `async_exec'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:46:in `block in execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:696:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:695:in `block in log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:687:in `log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:45:in `execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:322:in `create_table'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:929:in `block in method_missing'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `say_with_time'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `method_missing'
/mnt/c/projects/Ksnew/db/migrate/20211211075029_create_space_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:867:in `exec_migration'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:851:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1329:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1328:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `each'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `block in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1401:in `block in with_advisory_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `block in with_advisory_lock_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `with_advisory_lock_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1397:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "Spaces" does not exist
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:110:in `exec'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.3/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:110:in `async_exec'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:46:in `block in execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:696:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:695:in `block in log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:687:in `log'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:45:in `execute'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:322:in `create_table'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:929:in `block in method_missing'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:897:in `say_with_time'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `method_missing'
/mnt/c/projects/Ksnew/db/migrate/20211211075029_create_space_users.rb:3:in `change'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:867:in `exec_migration'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:851:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1037:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1329:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1380:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1328:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `each'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `block in migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1401:in `block in with_advisory_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `block in with_advisory_lock_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `with_advisory_lock_connection'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1397:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/keaton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Ksnew_with_pg_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: Ksnew_with_pg_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: Ksnew_with_pg_production
```

I also tried to execute the $psql command, but the following error message appeared

```
psql: FATAL: database "keaton" does not exist
```

I really don't know what to do, please teach me, thank you

Comment: Try making sure that there's a migration to create the needed `spaces` table first because that's necessary for creating the `space_users` (I think so) table.

Comment: How can I create a spaces table?

Comment: The same way you created the migration for the space_users (or someone else did), check the code for that migration and create a new one - which must be before the migration for the space_users table (they run in a sequential order). Most commonly `rails g migration Space name ...` (where `name` and all the following arguments are the table columns). You can check [this](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration) for further info.

Comment: I don't understand. I already have two models, Space and SpaceUser, and their columns are also available in the Schema. I want to re-migrate something that already exists? But what is the content of the migration?
  thanks!

Comment: If you have the models it doesn't mean the table must be there, same for the schema. Do you have any migration for creating the spaces table?

Comment: I have, that is my first migration "20211210143327_create_spaces.rb", this is its content:

`class CreateSpaces <ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
   def change
     create_table :spaces do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.string :icon

       t.timestamps
     end
   end
end`

Comment: So, if that migration is before the migration for creating `space_users`, then you can run `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate` and that should create them, otherwise create a new migration for your space_users, copy and paste the content make sure it goes after the migration to create the table `spaces` and run the migrations.

Comment: I repeated the three commands you suggested, but the same error message still appears in the final rails db:migrate. This is my project GitHub, I have no other way: https://github.com/KtKeaton/Kasuri

Comment: Can you try replacing the `references` argument to downcase? as in its table name, it should be `spaces` - downcase and plural. The arguments for references might coincide with the one for create_table in your migrations, something like this https://github.com/KtKeaton/Kasuri/blob/master/db/migrate/20211210143327_create_spaces.rb#L3